# Drag and drop in Angular 2

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

How to use this drag and drop library?

http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd

Author did not provide any tutorial how to import it (and does not answer on my emails) to my project what is unacceptable. Plumker example contains variables which are not defined etc. Did you use this library?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

How to use Library is here:
https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd

You can install

```
npm install ng2-dnd --save
```

Comment: but what should I import to my component?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the package in the project using:

```
npm install ng2-dnd --save
```

you have to include the package in your application module. The documentation (https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) of the package explains that as :

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {DndModule} from 'ng2-dnd';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DndModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

After doing this step, the package is included in your application and you don't need to import it in each of your component (unless you need any instance of services provided by the package).

Here is how he is using the directive in the component.

```
 <div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-info" (onDropSuccess)="simpleDrop=$event">
```